# PostgreSQL / Oracle => query to group and count hierarchical values

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql

I have this table on PostgreSQL, but I test it on Oracle DB.
    I need to extract counting data to check how many times the start and end 
    value repeats itself

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE
(
  KEY    VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
  ID     NUMBER,
  VALUE  VARCHAR2(2000 BYTE)
);
```

with these values:

```
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('Dia-001', 1, 'welcome');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('Dia-002', 1, 'welcome');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('Dia-002', 2, 'condizioni_app1');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('Dia-002', 3, 'condizioni');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('Dia-003', 1, 'welcome');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('Dia-003', 2, 'condizioni_app1');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('Dia-003', 3, 'condizioni_app2');
```

I would like to get this result

```
VALUE             NEXT              COUNT
welcome           condizioni_app1   2
condizioni_app1   condizioni        1
condizioni_app1   condizioni_app2   1
```

Note: If the value in the KEY field is single, it should not be counted 
(ex. for KEY 'Dia-001').
All pairs of values must be counted. For example for key 'Dia-002' we have 
pairs welcome/condizioni_app1, condizioni_app1/condizioni (id 1 and 2, 2 and 
3).

Answer (score 1):

One option is Postgres' [`lead` window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-window.html#FUNCTIONS-WINDOW-TABLE):

```
select  value
,       next_value
,       count(*)
from    (
        select  value
        ,       lead(value) over (partition by key order by id) as next_value
        from    MY_TABLE
        ) sub
where   next_value is not null
group by
        value
,       next_value
```

Or you could use a self-join to find the next value for the same key:

```
select  t1.value
,       t2.value
,       count(*)
from    MY_TABLE t1
join    MY_TABLE t2
on      t1.KEY = t2.KEY
and     t1.ID = t2.ID - 1
group by
        t1.value
,       t2.value
```

[Both examples at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/deda5/8/0)